# Setting up OpenVPN server and client

Tags: openvpn, internet

I have been trying to better understand how OpenVPN works and so I have setup a OpenVPN server and client through VMs on my machine. I have an Ubuntu VM acting as the OpenVPN server and a Kali machine as the OpenVPN client (since Kali does not come with firewalls I though this will make it easier).

I have managed to set it up, passed the TLS verifications, get a confirmed connection from the Kali to the server but I cannot browse the internet!! I have enabled port forwarding (both now and on restarts), I have setup the ufw firewall on the server to allow port 1194 UDP through, however I still believe it is due to some other firewall issue on the Ubuntu server side but I cannot workout what it is and how to fix it. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!!

Below are some useful diagnostics to help. If you need any more then please feel free to ask.

Note: Internet browsing works fine when VPN is not active.

client_before_VPN_enabled: netstat-rn

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0`

client_while_VPN_enabled: netstat-rn

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.5        128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.5        128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.96    192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0`

iptables on server side - there is more but I dont want to put it in as I dont want to make the post too long. 

`Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere`

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Any help you can give would be great. Thanks allot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your client can ping the address 'eth0' of your server I think you miss a NAT basic rule as "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE" for browsing to internet.